# display api response in html in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I hired a developer to help to create API. He displayed all results in `<br>` tag like so :

/public/index.ejs

```
function showResult() {
  item = window.items[window.currentPage];
  let result = '';
  for (i = 0 ; i < Object.keys(item).length ; i ++) {
    result = result + Object.keys(item)[i] + '=' + Object.values(item)[i] + '<br/>';
  }
  $("#result").html(result);
}
```

app.js

```
res.send(response['resp_result']['result']['products']['product']);
```

How do I display each object from the response in index.ejs like below ?

```
<div>price : {product_price} <span>{product_name}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
result = result + Object.keys(item)[i] + '=' + Object.values(item)[i] + '<br/>';
```

with

```
result = result + '<div>price : ' + Object.keys(item)[i] + ' <span>' + Object.values(item)[i] + '</div>';
```

except you don't have a closing tag for the `<span/>` - but I just made do what you put.

Also, I don't know which is the key and which is the value so you might have to swap `Object.keys(item)[i]` and `Object.values(item)[i]`